# Custom `catch` for all promises

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following function

```
const _error_handler = err => {
    console.log('[%s] %s - %s - %s', err.method.toUpperCase(), err.url, err.statusCode, err.statusMessage)
}
```

I want ALL my promises to automatically have that as it's catch block. So instead of doing

```
promise1
   .then(...)
   .catch(_error_handler)

promise2
   .then(...)
   .catch(_error_handler)
```

I want the `.catch(_error_handler)` to be implicit. Is this possible?

Comment: are you using the native Promise type?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes